# How to resolve HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: httpwebrequest, simple-html-dom

All,

I am accessing a web-page through command prompt using simple_html_dom in php as

```
  $page = file_get_html($url, false, $context);
```

where $url is the web-URL.
If you URL is like http://abc.com/xyz.html?s="sometext"
Then i am getting proper response. 
But I am getting HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request if the URL has white space in the get parameter like http://abc.com/xyz.html?s="some text".

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to encode the white space into %20?
http://abc.com/xyz.html?s=some%20text
The server have freedom to answer anything it wants based on your requests, so only the server maker can answer you question properly. Also, I have never seen URL parameters surrounded in quotes, it is an uncommon idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the parameter:

```
$text = urlencode('some text');
$url = "http://abc.com/xyz.html?s=$text";
$page = file_get_html($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: That'll encode everything, turning it into `http%3A%2F%2F...`, which is NOT going to work

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating that url yourself, you'll have to url_encode the query values:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/xyz.html?s=' . urlencode('some text');
```

which'll give you

```
http://example.com/xyz.html?s=some+text
                                  ^---spaces must be + in urls.
```